# How to delete duplicate records in wp_postmeta database table?

Tags: post-meta, mysql, duplicates

Some of my posts have two values for a meta key called `cb_full_width_post`. I want to only keep the records that have a meta value of `nosidebar-narrow`. This means I need to

1. Identify records in wp_postmeta that have the same post ID and also have an entry for the meta key `cb_full_width_post`
2. Delete all records identified in step 1 that do not have meta value of `nosidebar-narrow`

So far, I have come up with this SQL to identify posts with two or more values for the same meta key `cb_full_width_post`:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, count(*)
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'cb_full_width_post'
GROUP BY post_id, meta_key
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns a result set of wp_postmeta records having more than one value for `cb_full_width_post`.
I'm stuck on the next step.  I need to use the result set from the above query, which gives me the post IDs that I need to target.  I need to find those post IDs in wp_postmeta, and delete all records where `meta_value != 'nosidebar-narrow'`

Edit: some visual info

```
Record #1
post_id:     1  
meta_key:    cb_full_width_post   
meta_value:  Good

Record #2
post_id:     1
meta_key:    cb_full_width_post
meta_value:  Bad_if_duplicate

Record #3
post_id:     2
meta_key:    cb_full_width_post
meta_value:  Bad_if_duplicate
```

I only want to delete Record #2, because it has meta_value "Bad_if_duplicate" and because it is a duplicate (same post ID as Record #1).
Even though Record #3 has meta_value "Bad_if_duplicate", I don't want to delete it, because that is its only meta_value, i.e. it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a select statement to do this, a `DELETE` statement can handle finding the records. Make sure to backup your database first, then try the following SQL query.

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'cb_full_width_post'
AND meta_value != 'nosidebar-narrow'
```

Comment: That will delete all records with meta_value != 'nosidebar-narrow'.  It doesn't just target posts that have duplicates.  There are some records that have meta_value != 'nosidebar-narrow' that I need to keep.

Comment: @LeonardShelby I'm confused, are you trying to delete the whole post and all associated meta (from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables) or just the meta values? When you say "I want to only keep the records that have a meta value of nosidebar-narrow" that's exactly what the above query does.